# Locate in Delphi XE2 TADO exception with single quote in search value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Having trouble with Delphi XE2 (update2) using MS SQL 2008 R2 (sp 2) or with MS SQL 2005 (sp4).
form1.ado_m is via the TADO dataset with no parameter check using native 64 sql

```
var
  okd:boolean;
  dd:ansistring;
```

code snippet:

```
okd:=form1.ado_m.Locate('abcrow',dd,[loCaseInsensitive]);
```

If the value of dd ends in a single quote (it is converted to '' in the debugger) it gives a exception:

> Exception class EOleException with message 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'.

What is strange to me is that is a single quote character is the middle of var dd it works fine.
Workaround?

Comment: Try using `QuotedStr(dd)` instead of just `dd` in your locate statement, or changing the assignment of the value to `dd := QuotedStr(Something);`.

Comment: Mr. White - tried you quotedstr(dd). Gave me exception:First chance exception at $768FB9BC. Exception class EOleException with message 'Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value'.

Comment: Try StringReplace() and replace every single quote with two single quotes.

Comment: @bartrat: I can't explain the problem with `QuotedStr`, because you posted no code using it. In fact, you've posted no code showing the assignment of anything to `dd` whatsoever, even though you claim that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Mr. White,  It fails with dd being assigned the following value: dd:='A1020778014#;]_69BO''' ; 
dd:=quotedstr(dd);  okd:=form1.ado_m.Locate('abcrow',dd,[loCaseInsensitive]); 
FYI: without the quotedstr command it works fine with dd:='A0122063096*6\2!9B''S';

Comment: I couldn't give an answer without the 'problem' seach value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the **number sign** (#) AND **quote** together in the search value.

Locate use the ADO [find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method: The value in Criteria may be a string, floating-point number, or date. String values are delimited with **single quotes** or **"#" (number sign)** marks (for example, "state = 'WA'" or "state = #WA#").

Try to replace the number sign OR quote character by inserting records.

Another option is to use the OnFilterRecord and filtered property:

```
  ...
  FSearchValue := 'A1020778014#;]_69BO''';  // private field in TForm1
  ado_m.Filtered := true;
  try
    okd := not ado_m.IsEmpty;
  finally
    ado_m.Filtered := false;
  end;
  ...

procedure TForm1.ado_mFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := SameText(DataSet.FieldByName('abcrow').AsString, FSearchValue);
end;
```

Comment: Arjen van der Spek: Thanks so the suggestion, that is the problem all right. I could not find a dataset.find in XE2. I do not understand how the sametext would help me at all. Is there a way to present the # character as literal and not as a delimiter?

Comment: You can't use # and ` together in the Locate method but if you use the OnFilterRecord dataset evnt you can. Find is used inside the Locate method, it is not a public method.

Comment: Thanks for update Mr. Spek your suggestions and advice have been helpful.